# Why Can't I use an Organization Profile type in a Contribution Page?

Tags: civicontribute, profile

I want to create a contribution page for organizations specifically.  So, I create a profile with the "Organization Name" field.  This makes the profile type Organization (as opposed to Individual).  When setting up my contribution page I'm unable to select my Organization Type Profile from the drop-down menu (Individual Type Profiles work fine).

I have modified the "On Behalf Of Organization" profile to include the fields I desire and selected the [Allow individuals to contribute and / or signup for membership on behalf of an organization?] check-box.  Other than the user having to check a box to see Organization fields, this works fine.

The problem now is that I can't setup the form to be a "cid=0" URL form, which gives the user the option to lookup a contact record and have the fields populate upon selection.  The lookup works on the Organization form, but when I click the organization I want CiviCRM doesn't populate the fields and I get this error: "Error Mandatory key(s) missing from params array: profile_id"

The web form I have put together for Individuals works great with a "cid=0" URL for lookup and auto-populate.  Why can't a form with organization fields work the same?

Answer (score 2):

You kind of have two questions here: the second being an issue you ran across after addressing the first.

To start with, yes, the main profiles on a contribution form are limited to contribution fields, individual fields, and fields for all contact types.

The presumption is that only individuals have fingers to fill out a form; even if the form is an organization's membership or donation, it's really an individual *acting on behalf of* the organization.  However, you already solved this: you started using the "on behalf of organization" options.

I know the feature you describe with the `cid=0` for filling the donation form as someone else, but that box should only allow you to select individuals, since it's filling the parts of the form that are individual-specific.  Meanwhile, it wouldn't necessarily make sense to fill the organization fields, because an individual may have any number of relationships with organizations.

If someone were to extend CiviCRM to add a second box for selecting the organization that is related to the individual making the contribution, that would be a nice feature.  However, it doesn't do it at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew.  Makes sense.  I think one of the main challenges is that our organization has relationships with the organization donating, not the person in the donating organization.  So instead of Sally from ABC company donating, it's ABC company that's donating.  I'm essentially trying to create an easy for for staff to receive GIK donations.  This is easily done through the New Contribution page in Civi.  There I can easily specify Org name and fill out form.  So I'm trying to distill that New Contribution page to an easy web form.

Comment: Yeah, all the pieces are there, and it's something we could build without too much trouble, but it isn't all together in core.

Answer (score 0):

We use Drupal CiviCRM Webform to achieve this functionality. It allows us to record a contribution for an organization. In any case, we are not able to send the receipt with the information of the organization because the same reason, we can't embed a profile with organization fields.

> Cannot add or update profile field type Contribution with combination
>   of Activity or Membership or Participant or Household or Organization

Have you found any solution in this regard? Does anyone know if it is an intentional (and the reasons) or an undeveloped functionality?