# How to build a Drupal webform for individual/organization contributors

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, webform-civicrm

Is there any recipe to build a Drupal webform with the possibility to choose to contribute as an individual or as an organization?

I have tried enabling contact 1 as individual, contact 2 as organization and enabling a contribution page.

But if I fill contact 1 data, contribution is recorded successfully. And if I fill contact 2 data no contribution is recorded. Seems that webform contribution is only associated to first contact.

There is some way or some trick to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes:** you can use Webform CiviCRM to make a Contribution of behalf of an Organization -> make Contact 1: the Organization; and make Contact 2: the Individual;

**No:** you can not present this as a choice on the same webform - as the Contribution will be assigned to Contact 1; So: make a screen/page ahead of the webforms - with two nice buttons: "Contribute as Individual" "Contribute as Organization" -> and then link these to two different webforms;

Comment: In the absence of a solution that allows choice between a person and an organization contribution on the same webform I have chosen your suggestion to create two webforms separately.

Anyway, I have an issue not seeing organization submited data on sent contributions receipts for organizations. It seems necessary to embed a profile on the contribution page with organization fields but this isn't possible. See https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/12640/why-cant-i-use-an-organization-profile-type-in-a-contribution-page. Any suggestion to solve it?

Comment: How about generate a receipt from the Drupal side?

Comment: Yes, it seems the most realistic option while it is not possible to solve it in the other way.

Comment: And as a bonus you can make that Email really nice on the Drupal/webform side 

Comment: What I’ve started doing since is use CiviRules to trigger an Email (using a Message Template) to be sent out -> react on Post Contributiom. Because when you click Submit on the Webform the transaction has not happened yet. I used to create tokens for last contribution id, trxn_id, total_amount, etc but I think these are available in Fuzion’s CiviToken extension now.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 2 links in my menu to two different webforms, I made an image of a Yes Checkbox.[image: Checkbox with Yes]

At the top of my primary form (individual) I added a Markup component and put in the following code

```
<label >This donation is from an organization </label><a href="/donate-org" style="text-decoration:none; color:#444;"><img src="sites/default/files/images/BoxYes.png " alt="Donate from an organizations here" style="width:49px !important;">
```

This still feels like it is part of the form to donors but it actual is a link to my other form.

On my other form (organization) I did the same thing but pointed back to my individual form.

[image: screenshot of webform]

Comment: Clever solution, but the usability flaw is that when they start filling out the form and then click the button, all their entered data will be wiped.

Comment: That is why I have the Org question at the top of the form