# Using Webform CiviCRM for a contribution form and allow "on behalf of an organization"?

Tags: webform-civicrm

Drupal 7.63
Civi 5.4.1

We currently use a Civi Contribution Page for our donation form. However, I am looking at changing to using the Webform CiviCRM Integration module. However, our current Civi Page allows an organization donation using "On Behalf of".

But I do not see on behalf of in the webform options. But I can set the form to allow for Individual or Org contact type.

Any ideas how to do "On behalf of" or a simple way to have first option be Individual or Org and then display the proper Contact Form?

I have played with the [Webform Node Element](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_node_element) module (allows you to add a node as a webform component). But in order to use conditionals with it, you have to put the nodes (webform for individual and webform for orgs) into seperate fieldsets and show based on selection of Ind or Org question. Then because you have a full form within another form you have 2 Submit buttons. I can hide one with CSS but then I run into multi-page issues which seems to be required to process contributions.

I have also looked at the component keys for the Civi Contact components when set for Individual vs Org. I thought maybe they used a different key depending on if the form contact was individual or org. But that does not seem to be the case.

Any ideas out there of how to handle this?

Comment: See this related question [How to build a Drupal webform for individual/organization contributors](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/21173/how-to-build-a-drupal-webform-for-individual-organization-contributors)

Comment: Opps, I looked before I posted my question but I did not find that one. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of have 2 links in my menu to two different webforms, I made an image of a Yes Checkbox.[image]

At the top of my form I added a Markup component and put in the following code

```
<label >This donation is from an organization </label><a href="/donate-org" style="text-decoration:none; color:#444;"><img src="sites/default/files/images/BoxYes.png " alt="Donate from an organizations here" style="width:49px !important;">
```

This still feels like it is part of the form to donors but it actual is a link to my other form.